# Embedded web tab Facebook Fanpage

Tags: facebook-page

I want to create a tab on a Facebook fanpage, but this tab is a website developed and hosted on a server, is it possible?

I do not know if what I want to do it like they did [here](https://www.facebook.com/womchile/app/1435246463417372/), but create something similar